# Why do many kick scooters have such small wheels?

Tags: kick-scooter

Many kick scooters, including those for adults, have very small wheels:

[image: Kick scooter with small wheels]
*Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Circ_E-Scooter_Frankfurt_am_Main_IMG_0159.jpg)*

The wheels are much smaller than bicycle wheels.  Some kick scooters have larger wheels, but those are relatively rare:

[image: Kick scooter with larger wheels]
*Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2016-11-02-PHOTO-00000007.jpg)*

Or, for an example with full "bicycle sized" wheels:

[image: Kick scooter with full-sized wheels]
*Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tretroller_auf_Helgoland.JPG)*

I have not had the opportunity to try kick scooters with all types of wheels, so I cannot speak from experience which one rides best.  However, I would imagine that the ride is more stable with larger wheels.  What are the main reasons that many kick scooters have tiny wheels?  What are the advantages of larger vs. smaller wheels on kick scooters?

Comment: NB the top picture is an electric scooter; not all the same arguments apply. Especially note the two brake levers.  It's also a rental version, with different economics to a privately-owned one - hence the presence of things like lights and front suspension (which presumably works out better to the rental company than a bigger wheel) as well as the dual brakes

Comment: It's probably not a coincidence that the English name for big-wheel scooters is "kickbike", given that they're intermediate between a bike and a scooter

Comment: My 1920's kick scooter also had small wheels (and a rear-wheel brake). Whatever the answer, it's not just a modern phenomena.

Comment: @david Although the kick scooter in the third image in my question is undated, it does not look brand new either.  It seems that for both old and new kick scooters, most have small wheels, whereas a small minority have big wheels.

Comment: Given that your first photograph is of an electric scooter, and not a kick scooter, which did you really mean?  (Yes, electric scooters can often technically be propelled by kicking, but in reality, that's about as common as someone peddling a moped.)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket My question is agnostic about electric vs. active kick scooters.  For me the term "electric scooter" is ambiguous with electric mopeds, but I agree that few people would propel an electric kick scooter by kicking.

Comment: Making sense of this observation might be better served by asking "why do bikes have such big wheels?"

Comment: @Will there's a thing called an [A-bike](http://a-bike.co.uk/) with wheels almost as small as those on a scooter.    I've never seen one in real life, but there are folding bikes with not much bigger wheel.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket the (rental) electric scooters round here apparently have to be kicked into moving before the throttle will respond.  They're also geofenced so if you go out of area or the GPS glitches out they become unpowered kick scooters.  But you get fined if you leave them out of area, and the geofencing can be dumb. But they're still electric kick scooters

Comment: @ChrisH even a Brompton folding bike with its half-ish-sized wheels is almost impossible to balance with no hands. The relationship between steering and balancing that large-wheeled bikes create is just of less value on a kick scooter which gives more control over body weight positioning for balance and isn't expected to be so good for going long distances on two wheels alone.

Comment: @Will no hands is strictly optional - I could ride for 20 years before I even tried properly.  Now my hybrid and MTB are trivial but my tourer isn't, so it's not just wheel size.

Comment: @ChrisH the point of no-hands isn't that doing so is inherently important but that it requires more active input to balance because it's less stable. My experience of riding a Brompton is that it's simply less relaxing to ride than other bikes.

Answer (score 27):

I have seen a couple in real life with big front wheels (24"+), and they do seem like they would be a nicer ride on real roads, however:

- big-wheel scooters don't tend to fold
- even if they did, you might not be allowed to take them on public transport.  This is a major factor as scooters are good as a last-mile  means of transport, being a little quicker than walking.
- similarly, scooters are widely tolerated in pedestrian areas, e.g. on pavement (sidewalks).  Put a bike wheel on it and you might attract unwanted attention, as (unpowered) scooters may fall into a grey area in the law where bikes are definitely forbidden.
- little scooter wheels often have solid or foam-filled tyres.  While these can be used on bike-type wheels they're a pain to fit and costly.
- many scooters are so cheap that they're meant to be replaced when a single part wears out.  A spoked wheel with a pneumatic tyre has more to go wrong and costs more so you end up needing to repair it (even just punctures) or throw stuff away.
- punctures are a hassle scooter riders don't want to deal with
- the portability of a folding small-wheel scooter means you can take it into many workplaces etc. with you. It won't get stolen but you don't need a lock.

But I think the biggest issues are cost of manufacture:

- the small moulded or cast wheels on a typical scooter are really cheap to make.  They're going to cost a similar amount to manufacture as a bike's front hub, with the solid tyre being moulded on top.  A bike-type wheel as used on the big-wheel scooters pictured additionally needs a rim, spokes, an expensive machine or human to assemble it and a tyre & tube.  I'd expect it to cost roughly 5x as much.
- on top of that, the frame would be more expensive as it involves more metal
- a big back wheel would need a proper brake, rather than the combined mudguard/footbrake on many models, as that would come up too high to use

This translates to purchase price.  A basic adult scooter costs about as much as a pair of reasonable bike tyres, or a bike lock and helmet.  So the financial barrier is much lower.

Stability on smooth ground isn't a problem with small-wheeled scooters, but they're at risk from potholes etc.  That's partly due to the wheel's ability to roll over obstacles, but partly due to the location of the centre of mass close behind and well above the fulcrum formed by the front axle.  Using a bike front wheel helps with the first and third factors, but the user's bodyweight is still rather close behind the front axle.  This is one area where electric scooters benefit from the heavy battery  being low and the motor being low and at the back.

Comment: I can from personal, unplanned, experiments confirm the issue with the center of mass. Ahem.

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's my biggest worry about widespread adoption of electric scooters because at their higher speeds it risks serious injury even for sensible users (who currently seem to be a minority anyway) given the state of our roads

Comment: As the owner of an adult scooter, I agree with all of the points mentioned above.

Comment: @spikey_richie Do you own one with small, medium, or big wheels?

Comment: @gerrit small-medium. It's an Oxelo Town 7XL. https://www.decathlon.co.uk/p/mp/oxelo/refurbished-oxelo-town7-adult-scooter-x-large-a-grade/_/R-p-269d87ed-b224-49b1-b27c-c86e0399008b?mc=269d87ed-b224-49b1-b27c-c86e0399008b_c192&c=GREEN

Comment: @spikey_richie There is one point where I disagree: Punctures. If a scooter used a good puncture proof tire, scooter riders would not need to worry about punctures either. They are not as indestructible as a massive/foam tire, but indestructible enough to make punctures a non-issue. Sadly, good puncture proof tires would add to the cost issues, big time. And they would still require topping of the tire pressure from time to time.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica I ran marathon plus on my  commuter bike (now gator hardshell on the front).  That  doesn't allow me to get away without a puncture kit, I just have to use it very rarely

Comment: And the wheel cost goes up even more for electrified models: a small wheel can be driven directly by a motor, while larger wheel needs planetary gearbox in the hub motor to get equivalent forward force.

Comment: I've pushed over 10 000km on various skateboards. I've tried footbikes a few times, with medium and large wheels. Somehow, I kept kicking into the rear wheel and almost crashed a few times. The concept is nice, and once the thing is rolling, it rolls forever. It wasn't for me, though.

Comment: Related: Big wheels are going to be heavier than little wheels. Often a scooter (especially one without motor) is meant to be lightweight, so you can carry it much more easily than a bicycle.

Comment: @ChrisH Of course, that is a bit route dependent. For me, the same tire got the puncture frequency down to something around once in 10Mm (10000km). Low enough to forget about patching.

Comment: Foldability is a big deal. I used to use a scooter daily when I lived in a city with smooth paved sidewalks. I would use it to get to the metro stop, fold it up and get on the train, then use it again for the last leg of the journey, skipping the bus. Part of the way involved folding it up (takes a couple of seconds) and going up some stairs. At work I'd just keep it under my desk. If it's as big as a bike, there's little point in not just riding a bike instead.

Comment: I want to add one physics-related argument against big wheels. Bigger and heavier wheels mean higher angular momentum keeping the vehicle up right, like on a bike (if you spin up a wheel it doesn't like changing its plane, like a fidget spinner). On kick scooters you may want to frequently tilt a little when doing the kick and it wastes less energy if you have small wheels - i.e. smaller angular momentum.

Comment: @Marandil that's a good point. I reckon you could compromise on BMX size wheels in that case, given how sharply they change direction and how much they tend to lean when pedalled hard. PayPal personally though, I reckon the physics of what happens when the front wheel encounters uneven ground is a real limit on scooter performance and use. On a bike, potholes that you really must avoid (instead of just standing on the pedals) are visible from some distance away. On a scooter with small wheels, a much smaller hole is a real risk of stopping the front wheel

Answer (score 25):

If you're going to buy something as big as a bike **why not just buy a bike**?

Bikes are better than scooters. You can go faster with less effort. Now, some people will want a scooter for some reason that isn't about practicality, efficiency, speed, etc. Which is all good, but it's not much of a market. So mass market kick scooters all need to offer something that you can't get from a bike: size, foldability, cost, etc. That means bike sized scooters are simply excluded from the market regardless of their ability *as scooters*.

Comment: +1. The reason I nearly got one was that it would be easy to carry by bike+train. The other adults I've known to use them have always wanted that level of portability, though being able to get away with using it on the pedestrian pavement rather than the road was another factor for at least one.

Comment: Bikes aren't "better" than scooters... they are simply different.  In many situations, bicycles are more practical, efficient, and faster, but in a good number of situations the opposite is true.  You also need to consider that often scooters are less expensive to manufacture and to ship, and require minimal (or no) assembly before being used.  I have used both bicycles and scooters extensively, and each offers a different set of benefits.  Of course, on this site, claiming that *"bikes are better"* will obviously yield a handful of cheap upvotes.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Can you go faster with less effort on your scooter?

Comment: Never tried, but I strongly doubt it. But top speed with minimal effort is rarely the purpose of a kick scooter.  It's like why you'll never see a monster truck in a Formula 1 race, and why you'll never see a Ferrari in a monster truck race.  But if you know of such races, please do invite me, because those sound like great spectator sports!

Comment: For a short enough journey, unfolding a scooter (which can be done while walking along) and scooting can be quicker than unlocking a well-locked bike, especially if the bike rack is out of the way.  My 1.5km/mile from the station to work is barely quicker by bike than walking because of that and traffic lights; running is fastest of all but sweaty.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Then I stick by my claim "Bikes are better than scooters. You can go faster with less effort." and suggest you don't ignore the second part of the claim. (Also, I agree that would be fun)

Comment: @ChrisH: Indeed, which is the part about " So mass market kick scooters all need to offer something that you can't get from a bike: size, foldability, cost, etc.", a scooter with bike sized wheels isn't going to be easily carried and unfolded in that way.

Comment: @ JackAidley exactly.  If by "better" we mean "faster for less effort" than a bike's drivetrain will always win.  If "better" = "more suitable" then a folding scooter or indeed a good pair of running shoes may win.  As this isn't English.se I propose we accept the semantic ambiguity in the meaning of a common word, meaning that you and @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket can both be right - bikes are better, and they're not

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Surely the point is that a bike is better in most ways than *a scooter with bike-sized wheels*. There might be _some_ benefits remaining from the lack of a drive train, but a lot of the advantages in cost, ease of assembly, etc, which you attribute to scooters are a direct consequence of, or at least massively increased by, them having small solid wheels.

Answer (score 9):

The argument I often hear about scooters is practicallity: people buying them are usually constrained when it comes to storage. Either at home, or at destination where they are taken in the offices to avoid theft and damage risk. To bring them at destination, you also typically need to take them in an elevator (with the handle bar folded).

A scooter with bike wheels will then be much less practical for this application: on top of the wheel size, you also need some space for the handle bar folding mechanism.

About the ride quality, small wheel size doesn't seem to be an issue in practice: they are mostly ridden on hard surfaces, and are quite manoeuvrable. In some areas, they can also share the bike infrastructure, which is generally good enough for this wheel size.

This only applies to owned scooters, not the shared ones. The shared ones were historically derivated from these, that being said.

Answer (score 6):

A kick bike costs (very roughly)  five times more than a scooter.  Until recently, scooters were mostly for kids. This is not only a very cost sensitive market, storage space in family households is usually at a premium. Many people need to transport kids to parks for play - so portability of scooters is a significant factor.  Thinking back to when my kids were younger, even if  offered to gave me Kickbikes for the kids, I would have turned it down due to the logistical problems they would have created over traditional scooters. I

In more recent years scooters have become popular for recreation (skate parks and other places where skaters hang out - where larger wheels hold no advantage)  and 'last mile' transport.

When the benefits of a large wheel scooter become compelling, the situation is competing with a bicycle, which people are more familiar with.

Comment: Yup. Most people I see with scooters are using them for the "last mile" use case, where they carry them in the trunk of their car, in their backpack, or in their hands for the vast majority of the trip. That would be somewhere being very annoying and impossible with large wheels. I heard that in Seoul, there is a "taxi" service which will drive you home in your own car, then the driver moves to the next customer using an eScooter they carry with them. Again, totally impractical with large wheels.

Comment: @JörgWMittag there's something similar in some UK cities.  I don't know how that works given that it predates the boom in e-scooters, which are still mostly illegal here anyway (the only legal ones are part of licensed rental schemes but illegal ones are common). I suspect they technically used a small folding e-bike despite using the word "scooter"

Answer (score 2):

> Why do many kick scooters have such small wheels?

The one you've pictured is electric and possibly a rental. Small wheels mean you only need one gear ratio and the speed range will suffice for the masses. It also makes it cheaper to produce and cheaper to fix.

Slap a big wheel on there with just one gear and the user will have to push-start it to overcome the resistance. The battery will die quicker unless you can maintain top speed for extended periods.

Most people aren't looking to hit dangerous speeds like your [Footbike Columbia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/03/2016-11-02-PHOTO-00000007.jpg/800px-2016-11-02-PHOTO-00000007.jpg) picture. Could you imagine the impracticality of requiring your customers to have spandex and a helmet for safe operation of your product?

Answer (score 1):

I think most scooters around now are designed primarily around the idea of doing tricks and spins etc. Can't really imagine too many people at the skate park with 24 inch wheels going upside down.
Disclaimer to that, as with bikes there are of course cheaper versions that look the same but are not suitable for anything too extreme.

Comment: I've never seen a scooter with handles at a skateboard park.

Comment: The vast majority are designed as cheap city transportation, trick scooters are an extremely tiny percent